# How to discard changesets in local mode?

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2012 there is a new 'Local workspace' mode. This is great for several reasons:

- No checking in or out of files.
- Files are not read-only so interop with tools other than VS is not so painful.
- Commits are based on actual file changes. Not Visual Studios idea of what you touched.

However, in this mode, I am unable to discard changesets! 
Doing the normal `tf merge /discard` dance results in no file changes. 
Since commits are now based on file changes, Visual Studio doesn't detect any changes and won't let me commit the discard merge.

How can i discard changesets in Local workspace mode?

*Edit*: To be clear, I'm talking about a discarding a changeset from a branch as a merge candidate for another. For when you fix a bug in an older version of your product, and the bug fix doesn't apply to newer versions (branches).

Comment: Are you talking about rolling back a changeset that has been checked in to source control, or discarding a pending changeset from the local workspace?

Comment: @aclear16 I've clarified the question. Thanks for letting me know it wasn't clear.

Comment: Just to clarify, you still need to "check-in" your changes once you have them pended locally and want others to be able to consume them or have them take part in merges.  Is this just a typo or are you trying to merge changes that haven't been checked in.  Note, with local workspaces, you no longer need to explicitly check out a file.

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere The changeset is commited to, say, branch 'V1'. I don't want this changeset ever to be merged to 'V2', so I want to `TF DISCARD` it. This worked fine in VS2010 and continues to work in VS2012 unless you choose a 'Local workspace'. Local workspaces are the default in VS2012.

Comment: Committed isn't a term that applies to TFS source control. Changes are either "checked in" or "pending locally". If they are pending locally, you can right click a file and "discard pending changes". If the changes have been checked in, you need to right click on the branch in source control and rollback.

Comment: Or are you talking about doing a selective merge with the merge tool?

Comment: 'Commit' is a term from most Vcs's, sorry about that. I mean 'checked in'. Not looking to rollback the changeset, just avoid having it show up as a merge candidate in the merge tool, so it doesn't get merged by accident. In other words, discard it with the 'tf' command line tool.

Comment: I'm running headlong into the same wall. After doing the discard, there is nothing to check in so the discard is never saved. I would file this as a bug with MS. (I'm using the TFS Power Tools, not sure if trying it w/o them would make a difference)

Comment: @RobertJeppesen, are you saying that in a local workspace, if you run tf merge <source> <target> it pends merge operations, but then if you undo those and run tf merge <source> <target> /discard it doesn't pend any changes?

Comment: For example, I just ran this in a local workspace and it worked:
md src
echo 1 > src\foo
tf add src\foo
tf checkin . /r /i
tf branch src tgt
tf checkin . /r /i
echo 2 > src/foo
tf checkin . /r /i
tf merge src tgt /r /discard
tf checkin . /r /i
tf merge src tgt /r --> No changes to merge

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere You seem to think a `TF merge /discard` will undo a check-in. It won't. And I'm not trying to undo any check-in. I'm trying to make sure a check-in never gets merged to another branch. I still want it in its current branch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd6dxhfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @RobertJeppesen we definitely agree that tf merge /discard will not undo a checkin.  I am not sure what in my two above comments suggested that or if you thought aclear16's comments were mine. In the sequence of command that I wrote, you should see that I made a change in src/foo, checked it in, merge discarded it, checked that in and then tried to merge again to show that it didn't go into the tgt branch.  Let me know where the disconnect is.

Comment: @TaylorLafrinere Looking at your example again, I may have misread it.  Maybe `tf checkin` works from the command line, didn't try that. What failed for me was that the check-in button in VS2012 was disabled because no files had changed. I'll try that and report back later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in VS2012. The 'Check-in' (or rather 'CHECK-IN') button is disabled in this situation. Doing the check-in from the command-line worked.